# `pidof` check on host fails when docker container runs same app (e.g. apache2)

Tags: docker, init.d

The apache2 init script does a `pidof` check to detect if apache is already running.

```
    if pidof $DAEMON > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
            if [ -e $PIDFILE ] && pidof $DAEMON | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -w $(cat $PIDFILE) > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
                    AP_RET=2
            else
                    AP_RET=1
            fi
...
            elif [ $AP_RET = 1 ] ; then
                    APACHE2_INIT_MESSAGE="There are processes named 'apache2' running which do not match your pid file which are left untouched in the name of safety, Please review the situation by hand".
```

(File: /etc/init/apache2 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS - truncated for brevity)

However, on a docker host, the VM containers may already have apache in them.  In this case `pidof` returns non-empty even if there is no apache running on the host.

```
$ sudo service apache2 stop
$ pidof apache2
32742 32480 32379 32365 31295 31294 31293 31292 31291 31274 31270
```

This means that the init script succeeds only when *all* docker containers with apache in them have stopped (or not yet started).  Consequently, apache on the host cannot be `restart`ed.

How does one fix this situation so that the host's apache can be restarted independently of the VMs?  Is there a version of `pidof` that will only detect pids owned directly by init?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too bad there's a `# can't use pidofproc from LSB here` in the init script, without real explanation. I'd still consider this apache2 script to have a bug worthy of a report.

TL;DR: solution: replace `pidof apache2` with `pgrep --ns 1 ^apache2$` (or if this doesn't work, `pgrep --ns 1 --nslist uts ^apache2$`)

Long explanation about namespaces with an example that I wrote before finding `pgrep` could do it following:

Once you have the "candidates" using `pidof`, here's a method to separate them: check their namespaces, and compare them to `pid 1` (init/systemd)'s namespaces. Example using `lxc` and the `inetd` process, but this is container's technology and process' name agnostic:

```
# lxc-start stretch-amd64
# pidof inetd
10285 3372
# ls -l /proc/1/ns/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:49 cgroup -> cgroup:[4026531835]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:49 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:49 mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:49 net -> net:[4026531993]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:49 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:49 pid_for_children -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:49 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:49 uts -> uts:[4026531838]
# ls -l /proc/3372/ns/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:51 cgroup -> cgroup:[4026531835]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:51 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:51 mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:51 net -> net:[4026531993]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:51 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:51 pid_for_children -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:51 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:51 uts -> uts:[4026531838]
# ls -l /proc/10285/ns/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:50 cgroup -> cgroup:[4026532516]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:50 ipc -> ipc:[4026532415]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:50 mnt -> mnt:[4026532410]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:50 net -> net:[4026532418]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:50 pid -> pid:[4026532416]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:50 pid_for_children -> pid:[4026532416]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:50 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 nov.   9 19:50 uts -> uts:[4026532414]
```

Here it's clearly visible that `pid 3372` shares `pid 1`'s namespaces. `3372` is running on the host. `10285` doesn't share any namespace (ok user is the same: container run as root), so it's in a container. It's possible that sometimes some program running on the host has some of these changed for some reason (usually security related), but what shouldn't is the uts (hostname) namespace. So here's a script using `stat` and that given the process' name in arg "$1" (eg: `set -- inetd` or a script's argument) will give only the process in the same uts namespace, usually meaning the (same) host.

```
pid1uts="$(stat -c %N /proc/1/ns/uts|cut -d' ' -f3)"
for i in $(pidof "$1"); do
    if [ "$pid1uts" = "$(stat -c %N /proc/$i/ns/uts|cut -d' ' -f3)" ]; then
        echo $i
    fi
done | xargs -r
```

which in my example, returns `3372`.

I explained how to do it, but why reinvent the wheel when `pgrep` has options to handle it:

```
# pgrep ^inetd$
3372
10285
# pgrep --ns 1 --nslist uts ^inetd$
3372
```

Or for most of the cases just:

```
# pgrep --ns 1 ^inetd$
3372
```

Answer (score 0):

if your service on host listening on port 80 you can figure out process id with netstats

```
#netstat -plan | grep :80
```

container processes should be bind with other port number on host and internally in container with 80 port. so you can easily figure out host process and kill it.

Comment: As a SysAdmin, I know how to distinguish between processes in `netstat`, `lsof`, etc.  This needs to be a scriptable solution.